# Printing a list in Python L1 = [i for i in range(ord('A'), ord('K'))] print(L1)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print the ASCII codes of the alphabets from A to K in Python.I did this using the following code .

```
L1 = [i for i in range(ord('A'), ord('K'))]
print(L1)
```

I got this as the output

```
[65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]
```

Now i want it to be printed using the index values

```
    print ("List index-value are : ") 
for i in range(len(L1)): 
    print (i, end = " ") 
    print (L1[i])
```

the output is

```
List index-value are : 
0 65
1 66
2 67
3 68
4 69
5 70
6 71
7 72
8 73
9 74
```

The desired output i want is

> Blockquote

```
A 65
B 66
C 67
D 68
E 69
F 70
G 71
H 72
I   73
J 74
```

Comment: [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) is the inverse of `ord`.

Comment: "code i run was 
L1 = [i for i in range(ord('A'), ord('K'))] print(L1)
print ("List index-value are : ") 
for i in range(len(L2)): 
    print (i, end = " ") 
    print (L2[i])
output
List index-value are : 
0 65
1 66
2 67
3 68
4 69
5 70``
6 71
7 72
8 73
9 74

i want the output to return the alphabets instead of number. The output should look like

List index-value are : 
a 65
b 66
c 67
d 68
e 69
f 70
g 71
h 72
i 73
j 74

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post L2

Comment: Thanks Frank ! L2 has the value of L1 actually i was doing some operation and i a beginer in python .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As L1 is a list of enumerated chars from A to K, you can easily do the same the other way.

```py
L1 = [i for i in range(ord('A'), ord('K'))]
print("List index-value are : ")
for i in range(len(L1)):
    print('{} {}'.format(chr(L1[i]), L1[i]))
```